# Android with Eclipse Buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, button, onclick

I'm just starting out with the Android/Eclipse SDK and I have no previous Java experience.

I've seen lots of tutorials for running Toasts onclick but I'm trying to make it so that when a button is clicked a text field is populated with the text of that button.

In other words if I press a button which is labelled as 'Hello' then the contents of a textfield will become 'Hello'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried? made an xml layout and java side implementation, show us..

Comment: I would advise you to watch some java tutorials so you understand the logic behind the code :)

Answer (score 0):

write code in `onClick()`

```
String text = view.getText();
// use toast here to display text..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
Button mbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mText.setText("Hello");

            }
        });
```

Hope i may works..

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it up. You must have a "button1" and a "textview1" defined in your main.xml.

```
package my.dummy.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button b=null;
    TextView tv=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); // button1 set in main.xml
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1); // textview1 set in main.xml
    }

    public void onClick( View v ) {
        if (v == b) {
            tv.setText( b.getText() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working a treat. Thank-you very much!  I only have one extra question to ask.  If I were change the target from a Textview to string, how should I adjust the code?

Comment: Yes, getText() return type is CharSequence. That can be easily converted with toString() method, e.g. by replacing the `setText` line like this:  
`String str = b.getText().toString();`
`tv.setText( str );`

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your button's id is button1, and textview's id is textview1

```
       
Button My_Button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

My_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onclick(View v){
           textView.setText("hello");
      }
);
```